# Displaying textbox upon checking of checkbox in a CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I added a Checkboxlist from the toolbox to the Login page on my website.

Once I check a ListItem in the CheckBoxList (when clicked), I want three textboxes to be opened on the right side of the ListItem that was just checked (for example: Username, Password and ID textboxes).

I've been trying to do this all day, but I'm still struggling with it. Here's my c# code + image at the end:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (IsPostBack)
    return;
}

protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue == "1") 
{
    multiView.ActiveViewIndex = 0; 
}
}
}
```

See this below image for what I did .

[image]

[image]

this is the source aspx view.

Comment: Can you also post the markup in the .aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

> Add that three textboxe's in one div and set visible false in first time , Then set visible true for the div tag when you click the checkbox list .

for your div tag is in client side

```
<div id="xx" runat="server" > ////three textboxe's </div>
```

and  set visible false in page load and the set visible true in your checkbox selected index changed event on code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
xx.Visible=false;
if (IsPostBack)
    return;
}

protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue == "1") 
{
    xx.Visible=true;
}
}
```

Comment: i've just tried this, but nothing happens when i press GYM in the CheckBoxList. Here's an image of the source aspx:  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/811/yqxt.jpg/

Comment: Check your CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged1 Name ? Is it correct or not ? and put break point here for it fired or not !!!

Comment: @user2868855 Put mark us answer if my answers helped you ,because it's will helps to some others ..!!! cheers !